# Add a new row in spotfire

Tags: visualization, rows, spotfire

I have a dataset and I want to analyze the shift wise performance.

For example:
Crew 2 made last connection is at 09-08-2017 05:00:00 and the shift ends at 09-08-2017 06:00:00

After a few minutes crew 1, whose shift starts at 09-08-2017 06:00:00, make a connection @ 09-08-2017 06:03:00. But all the work for the latest connection was done by crew 2. I want to attribute that work to crew 2 instead of crew 1.

What I want to do is add two new rows, one just before 09-08-2017 06:00:00 and one just after 09-08-2017 06:00:00 to represent the work done by crew 2 and crew 1 respectively.

so for example, something like 09-08-2017 05:59:59 for crew 2 and 09-08-2017 06:01:00 for crew 1.

Please refer to the attached screenshot of the dataset. I need to add rows between column Id 1 and column Id 2.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lj7Xb.png)

Comment: The data description:
Crew: what crew is working
Time: Time index in GMT
Value: the amount of work done in ft
Column Id: the row Id
Minute: the difference between last time index and current time index.

Comment: Can you please provide more details? The question seems a little confusing to me. Perhaps rephrase it to make it much more clear.